# React-leaflet v3 and leaflet-contextmenu plugin problem with map instance

Tags: reactjs, plugins, leaflet, react-leaflet

There is no map instance in react-leavlet-v3 available.

And so leaflet-contextmenu from
https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu
is not working.

The Example show my problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/show-problem-leaflet-contextmenu-on-react-leaflet-v3-o2x6z?file=/src/MapView.js

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/), just a bit hard to find: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the map instance using `whenCreated` prop on MapContainer

```
<MapContainer
        className="markercluster-map"
        center={currentLocation}
        zoom={zoom}
        maxZoom={18}
        contextmenu={true}
        contextmenuItems={[
          {
            text: 'Zoom in',
            callback: this.zoomIn
          },
          { text: 'Zoom out', callback: this.zoomOut }
        ]}
        whenCreated={(map) => this.setState({ map })}
      >
   ...
</MapContainer>
```

and then on your event listeners

```
zoomOut = () => {
    const { map } = this.state;
...
}
zoomIn = () => {
    const { map } = this.state;
...
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3-and-leaflet-contextmenu-plugin-problem-with-map-instance-ds0s9)